# Flying effect in HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my scenario,

I have an image named img.png shown on top of a page, I have another image named fly_img.png (same size of img.png) located at the bottom of the page.

I've built a button, when I click it I would like the fly_img.png to fly/animate and be placed over the img.png.

I can't achieve the above scenario. But I tried some code, let me share it with you.

```js
$("#clickme").click(function() {


  var p = $("#img").offset();

  var v = $("#fly_img").offset();

  $("#fly_img").animate({
    opacity: 1,
    bottom: v.top - p.top,
    left: v.left - p.left
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete. 
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <button id="clickme">
    Click here
  </button>
  <br />
  <img id="img" src="img.png" alt="" "> 
  <br /> 
  <div style ="padding-left :350px;padding-top:150px "> 
    <img id ="fly_img " src="fly_img.png " style="position: absolute; "alt=" "/> 
  </div>
```

Comment: is it possible to post jsfiddle to understand better!?

Comment: There's no reason to use jsfiddle for this. Stack Overflow has a runnable code snippet feature now.

Comment: @rnevius am sorry i was trying to little lazy :) i have posted my solution below now!

Comment: Thanks for the response,here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/premkumar_ks16/qgtxbx57/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$("#clickme").click(function () { 
    var p = $("#img").offset(); 
    var v = $("#fly_img").offset(); 

    $("#fly_img").css({"top": v.top+"px", "left": v.left+"px"}); 

    $("#fly_img").animate({ 
        opacity: 1, 
        top:p.top, 
        left:p.left 
        }, 1000, function () { 
        // Animation complete. 
        }); 
});
```

This will make the picture fly from it's current spot to the other image's spot.
working fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8nfqqcy/)

Comment: Pretty sure this is exactly what the OP was looking for. Beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You defining in the `animation` function where your image should go to. So you just need to set the left and top animation attributes to the one where the image should fly to:

```
var to = $("#img").offset(); 
var from = $("#fly_img").offset(); 

$("#fly_img").animate({ 
  opacity: 1, 
  top:to.top, 
  left:to.left 
}, 1000, function () { 
  // Animation complete. 
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/9s22xhsd/1/

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `absolute` positioning and then animating the `left` and `top`, you could also use just the CSS `transition`:

```js
/* jQuery */

$("#btn1").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#ifly").addClass("anim");
});
$("#btn2").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#ifly").removeClass("anim");
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

#i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px; top: 50px;
}

#ifly {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%; top: 60%; 
    transition: 1s all ease;
}

#ifly.anim {
    left: 50px; top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Click" />
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="Reset" />
<hr/>
<img id="i" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100" />
<img id="ifly" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
```